# Close-form for integral $T(n)=\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{1}{1+\sin^n(x)}dx$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, closed-form, trigonometric-integrals

**Context:**

I have recently become interested in integrals of the form $$T(n)=\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{dx}{1+\sin(x)^n},$$
and I conjecture that $T(n)$ has a closed form evaluation for all $n\in\Bbb Z_{\ge0}$, or at least all non-negative even integers $n$. Trivially, one has $T(0)=\pi/4$. Less trivially, there is $T(1)=1$ (easy with $t=\tan(x/2)$), and $T(2)=\frac\pi{2\sqrt{2}}$ as seen [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3470594/583016). The integral $J=T(3)$, however, is not so easy.
We see that this integral is $$3J=\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{dx}{1+\sin x}-\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\sin (x)dx}{\sin(x)^2-\sin(x)+1}+2\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{dx}{\sin(x)^2-\sin(x)+1}.$$
The first integral is easy, and we get
$$3J=1-J_1+J_2.$$
The next integral is 
$$J_1=\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\sin (x)dx}{\sin(x)^2-\sin(x)+1},$$
which is, from $t=\tan(x/2)$,
$$J_1=2\int_0^1\frac{\frac{2t}{1+t^2}}{(\frac{2t}{1+t^2})^2-\frac{2t}{1+t^2}+1}\frac{dt}{1+t^2},$$
which is the awful
$$J_1=4\int_0^1\frac{tdt}{t^4-2t^3+6t^2-2t+1}.$$
I found that nothing but brute force could tackle this integral, so I used partial fractions and got
$$J_1=4\sum_{a\in A}\frac{1}{f'(a)}\left(1+a\log(1-a)-a\log(-a)\right)$$
where $$A=\left\{\frac12\left(1+p_1i\sqrt3+p_2\sqrt{-6+2p_3i\sqrt3}\right):p_1,p_2,p_3\in\{-1,1\}\right\}$$
is the set of roots of the polynomial $f(z)=z^4-2z^3+6z^2-2z+1,$
and $\log(z)$ is the complex logarithm.

However, the remaining integral is a little worse. We have from the substitution $t=\tan(x/2)$ the awful
$$J_2=4\int_0^1\frac{1+t^2}{1-2t+5t^2-2t^3}dt.$$
We can do the same sort of trick here as with the last integral and get
$$J_2=4\sum_{b\in B}\frac1{g'(b)}\int_0^1\frac{t^2+1}{t-b}dt$$
where $$B=\{z\in\Bbb C: 1-2z+5z^2-2z^3=0\}$$
is the set of roots of the polynomial $g(z)=1-2z+5z^2-2z^3$. These roots do indeed have [explicit evaluations](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1-2x%2B5x%5E2-2x%5E3). The integral in the summation is easy enough to calculate, but I'm not going to, as we already see that the integral has a closed form.

Next up, [Wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+1%2F%281%2Bsin%5E4+x%29+from+0+to+pi%2F2) evaluates $$T(4)=\int_0^1\frac{dx}{1+\sin(x)^4}=\frac\pi4\sqrt{1+\sqrt2},$$
as well as $$T(6)=\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{dx}{1+\sin(x)^6}=\frac{\pi}{12}(\sqrt{2}+2\sqrt{3}),$$
which is [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+1%2F%281%2Bsin%5E6+x%29+from+0+to+pi%2F2).

In fact, we may evaluate $T(2n)$ in terms of hypergeometric functions, which may have a general closed form. We do so by noting that
$$\frac{1}{1+\sin(x)^{2n}}=\sum_{k\ge0}(-1)^k\sin(x)^{2nk}$$
so that
$$T(2n)=\sum_{k\ge0}(-1)^k\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin(x)^{2nk}dx=\frac{\sqrt\pi}{2}\sum_{k\ge0}(-1)^k\frac{\Gamma(nk+\tfrac12)}{(nk)!}.$$
This is 
$$T(2n)=\frac\pi2\,_{n}F_{n-1}\left(1-\tfrac{1}{2n},A_n;B_n;-1\right)$$
where 
$$\begin{align}
A_n&=\left\{\frac{2r+1}{2n}:0\le r\in\Bbb Z\le n-2\right\}\\
B_n&=\left\{\frac{r}{n}:1\le r\in\Bbb Z\le n-1\right\}.
\end{align}$$
Whether or not this hypergeometric has a closed form I am unsure, but it looks simple enough to be evaluated exactly.

**Questions:**

*Can* $T(n)$ be computed in closed form of all $n$? If not, when can it be computed in closed form?

And at the very least, what is $T(5)$? It seems to be very nasty.

Thanks!

Comment: I think this can be done with the Weierstrass substitution $u=\tan (x/2)$. This will convert the integral to the integral of a rational function which can be done in closed form.

Comment: \begin{align}T(2n)=\int_0^\infty \frac{(1+x^2)^{n-1}}{(1+x^2)^n+x^{2n}}\,dx\end{align} probably contour integral is the simpler to compute $T(2n)$.

Comment: For $T(1)$ it's easier to multiply the top and bottom by $1-\sin x $: $$\frac{1}{1+\sin x}=\frac{1-\sin x}{\cos^2 x}=$$

Comment: @OliverJones interesting.... elaborate in an answer?

Comment: @FDP damn I really gotta learn complex analysis... any sources you'd recommend?

Comment: @Zacky you make every integral easier

Comment: Thanks for the nice words :D

Comment: @Clathratus: Try https://www.maa.org/press/maa-reviews/complex-analysis-an-introduction-to-the-theory-of-analytic-functions-of-one-complex-variable this book contains a lot of chapters about complex analysis but nothing about Jordan's lemmas as https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan%27s_lemma

Comment: BTW: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#General

Comment: \begin{align}T(2n)=\pi\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k\binom{2nk}{nk}}{2^{2nk+1}}\end{align}

Comment: @clathratus If you make the substitution, the resulting rational function can be integrated using partial fractions. The answer involves the $n$th roots of $-1$, as in Szeto's answer.

Comment: There is no way to reduce $T(2n)$ to $_{n}F_{n-1}$ as in the posted formula $$T(2n)=\frac\pi2\,_{n}F_{n-1}\left(1-\tfrac{1}{2n},A_n;B_n;-1\right).$$ This is *not* a hypergeometric function. It may be a Fox-Wright or Fox-H function though.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The close-form result, valid for both odd and even $n$, is
$$T(n) = \frac{1-(-1)^n}{2n}+ \frac1n \sum_{k=1}^{[\frac n2]}\beta_{k}^+(\frac\pi2+\tan^{-1}\beta_k^-)- \beta_k^- \coth^{-1} \beta_k^+
\tag1$$
with
$$\beta_k^{\pm }= \frac1{\sqrt2}\left(\sqrt{\cot\frac{(2k-1)\pi}{2n}}  \pm \sqrt{\tan\frac{(2k-1)\pi}{2n}} \right)
$$

---

Proof: Note

$$\frac1{1+y^n}=-\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{e^{i\theta_k}}{y-e^{i\theta_k}}, \>\>\>\>\>
\theta_ k = \frac{(2k-1)\pi}n$$
and combine conjugate pairs

$$\frac1{1+y^n}=\frac{1-(-1)^n}{2n(1+y)} + \frac2n \sum_{k=1}^{[\frac n2]} \frac{1-y \cos\theta_k }{y^2-2y\cos\theta_k+1} $$
Set $y = \cos x$ to integrate

\begin{align}
T(n)&=\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{dx}{1+\sin^n x}
= \int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{dx}{1+\cos^n x} \\
&= \frac1{2n}\int_0^{\frac\pi2}\frac{1-(-1)^n}{1+\cos x}dx
 + \frac2n \sum_{k=1}^{[\frac n2]} \int_0^{\frac\pi2} \frac{1-\cos x \cos\theta_k }{\cos^2x-2\cos x\cos\theta_k+1}dx\\
&= \frac{1-(-1)^n}{2n}
+ \frac2n \sum_{k=1}^{[\frac n2]} \int_0^{1} \frac{\tan^2\frac{\theta_k}2-t^2}{\tan^2\frac{\theta_k}2 +t^4}dt
\end{align}
where the half-angle substitution $t=\tan\frac x2$ is applied. Then, integrate over $t$ to arrive at the close-form expression (1). Note that the general result (1) simplifies considerably for even $n$ as the summation over the inverse trig functions vanishes. Explicitly, for $n =2m$
$$T(2m)= \frac\pi{4m} \sum_{k=1}^{m} \sqrt{\csc\theta_k+1}\tag2
$$
where $\beta_k^+ = \sqrt{\csc\theta_k+1}$ is recognized.

---

Listed below are some actual results per the close-form (1) or (2).

Even $n$:
\begin{align}
T(2) &= \frac\pi4 \sqrt{\csc\frac\pi2+1}=\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt2}\\
T(4) &= \frac\pi8 \left(\sqrt{\csc\frac\pi4+1}
 + \sqrt{\csc\frac{3\pi}4+1} \right)=\frac{\pi}{4}\sqrt{\sqrt2+1}\\
T(6) &= \frac\pi{12} \left(\sqrt2+\sqrt{\csc\frac\pi6+1}
 + \sqrt{\csc\frac{5\pi}6+1} \right)=\frac{\pi}{12}(\sqrt2+2\sqrt3)\\
T(8) &= \frac\pi8 \left(\sqrt{\csc\frac\pi8+1}
 + \sqrt{\csc\frac{3\pi}8+1} \right)\\
&=\frac{\pi}{8}\left(\sqrt{\sqrt{2(2+\sqrt2)}+1}
 + \sqrt{\sqrt{2(2-\sqrt2)}+1}\right)\\
T(10) &= \frac\pi{10} \left(\frac1{\sqrt2}+\sqrt{\csc\frac\pi{10}+1}
 + \sqrt{\csc\frac{3\pi}{10}+1} \right)\\
&=\frac{\pi}{10}\left(\frac1{\sqrt2}+ \sqrt[4]5+\sqrt{2+\sqrt5}\right)\\
T(12) &= \frac{\pi}{12} \sqrt{1+\sqrt2}\left(1+ \sqrt{2+2\sqrt3}\right)
\end{align}

Odd $n$:
\begin{align}
T(3) &=\frac13 +\frac{\sqrt[4]3+\frac1{\sqrt[4]3}}{3\sqrt2} \left(\frac\pi2+ \tan^{-1} \frac{\sqrt[4]3-\frac1{\sqrt[4]3}}{\sqrt2} \right)
- \frac{\sqrt[4]3-\frac1{\sqrt[4]3}}{3\sqrt2} \coth^{-1} \frac{\sqrt[4]3+\frac1{\sqrt[4]3}}{\sqrt2} 
\\
 T(5) &=\frac15 +\frac15\sqrt{ \sqrt{2+\frac2{\sqrt5}}+1}
\left(\frac\pi2+ \tan^{-1} \sqrt{ \sqrt{2+\frac2{\sqrt5}}-1}\right)
\\
 &\hspace{10mm} +\frac15\sqrt{ \sqrt{2-\frac2{\sqrt5}}+1}
\left(\frac\pi2- \tan^{-1} \sqrt{ \sqrt{2-\frac2{\sqrt5}}-1}\right)
\\
 &\hspace{10mm} -\frac15\sqrt{ \sqrt{2+\frac2{\sqrt5}}-1}
\coth^{-1} \sqrt{ \sqrt{2+\frac2{\sqrt5}}+1}
\\
 &\hspace{10mm} +\frac15\sqrt{ \sqrt{2-\frac2{\sqrt5}}-1}
\coth^{-1} \sqrt{ \sqrt{2-\frac2{\sqrt5}}+1}
\\
 T(7) &=\frac17 +\frac17\sqrt{ \csc\frac\pi7+1}
\left(\frac\pi2+ \tan^{-1} \sqrt{ \csc\frac\pi7-1}\right)
\\
 &\hspace{10mm} +\frac17\sqrt{ \csc\frac{3\pi}7+1}
\left(\frac\pi2+ \tan^{-1} \sqrt{ \csc\frac{3\pi}7-1}\right)
\\
 &\hspace{10mm} +\frac17\sqrt{ \csc\frac{5\pi}7+1}
\left(\frac\pi2- \tan^{-1} \sqrt{ \csc\frac{5\pi}7-1}\right)
\\
 &\hspace{10mm} -\frac17\sqrt{ \csc\frac{\pi}7-1}
\coth^{-1} \sqrt{ \csc\frac{\pi}7+1}
\\
 &\hspace{10mm} -\frac17\sqrt{ \csc\frac{3\pi}7-1}
\coth^{-1} \sqrt{ \csc\frac{3\pi}7+1}
\\
 &\hspace{10mm} +\frac17\sqrt{ \csc\frac{5\pi}7-1}
\coth^{-1} \sqrt{ \csc\frac{5\pi}7+1}
\\
\end{align}

Comment: fantastic! what an elegant solution!

Comment: Going over this answer again, I notice that you may have made an error in your claim that $$\int_0^{\frac\pi2} \frac{1-\cos x \cos\theta_k }{\cos^2x-2\cos x\cos\theta_k+1}dx=\int_0^{1} \frac{\tan^2\frac{\theta_k}2-t^2}{\tan^2\frac{\theta_k}2 +t^4}dt.$$ Specifically, after simplification, I get  $$\int_0^{\frac\pi2} \frac{1-\cos x \cos\theta_k }{\cos^2x-2\cos x\cos\theta_k+1}dx=\int_0^{1} \frac{\tan^2\frac{\theta_k}2\color{red}{+}t^2}{\tan^2\frac{\theta_k}2 +t^4}dt.$$

Comment: I was able to verify this using desmos: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/73p9wxzv7v

Comment: I get, verified by Desmos, $$T(n)=\frac{1-(-1)^n}{2n}+\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}J(\tan\tfrac{2k+1}{2n}\pi),$$ where $$J(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2x}}\left\{\frac{x-1}{2}\log\frac{1+x+\sqrt{2x}}{1+x-\sqrt{2x}}+(x+1)\left([0<x<1]\pi+\arctan\frac{\sqrt{2x}}{x-1}\right)\right\},$$ and $[0<x<1]$ is the Iverson Bracket

Answer (score 6):

As a suggestion, use $\tan\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)=t$ whenever the trig function is raised to an odd power, but use $x=\tan t$ when the trig is raised to an even power, that is since there will be no square roots left.

For even $n$, using the above, $T(6)$ can be simplified to:
$$T(6)=\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} \frac{dx}{1+\sin^6x}= \int_0^\infty \frac{(1+x^2)^2}{(2+x^2)(1+x+x^2)(1-x+x^2)}dx$$$$=\frac13\int_0^\infty\frac{dx}{2+x^2}+\frac16\int_0^\infty \left(\frac{1+x}{1-x+x^2}+\frac{1-x}{1+x+x^2}\right)dx $$
And one can see now easier how that nice result appears.

Similary, for $T(8)$ we have:
$$T(8)=\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{dx}{1+\sin^8 x}\overset{x\to \frac{\pi}{2}-x}=\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{dx}{1+\cos^8 x}\overset{x\to \tan^{-1} x}=\int_0^\infty \frac{(1+x^2)^3}{(1+x^2)^4+1}dx$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^\infty   \frac{x^2+1+\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}}{(x^2+1)^2+\sqrt 2 (x^2+1)+1}dx+\frac12\int_0^\infty\frac{x^2+1-\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}}{(x^2+1)^2-\sqrt 2 (x^2+1)+1}dx$$
$$=\frac{\pi}{8}\left(\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2(2+\sqrt 2)}}+\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2(2-\sqrt 2)}}\right)$$

---

For odd $n$, with the Weierstrass substitution after putting $x\to \frac{\pi}{2}-x$ we have:
$$T(3)=\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{dx}{1+\cos ^3 x}=\int_0^1 \frac{(1+x^2)^2}{1+3x^4}dx=\frac13+\frac23\int_0^1\frac{\frac13+x^2}{\frac13+x^4}dx=\frac13+\frac23f\left(\frac13\right)$$

> And at the very least, what is $T(5)$? It seems to be very nasty.

$$T(5)=\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{1}{1+\sin^5 x}dx\overset{x\to\frac{\pi}{2}-x}=\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{1}{1+\cos^5 x}dx\overset{\tan\frac{x}{2}\to x}=\int_0^1 \frac{(1+x^2)^4}{1+10x^4+5x^8}dx$$
$$=\frac15\int_0^1 dx+\frac25\int_0^1\frac{1+\frac{2}{\sqrt 5}+x^2}{1+\frac{2}{\sqrt 5}+x^4}dx+\frac25\int_0^1\frac{1-\frac{2}{\sqrt 5}+x^2}{1-\frac{2}{\sqrt 5}+x^4}dx$$
$$=\frac15+\frac25f\left(1+\frac{2}{\sqrt 5}\right)+\frac25f\left(1-\frac{2}{\sqrt 5}\right)$$

---

$$f(t)=\int_0^1 \frac{t+x^2}{t+x^4}dx\overset{x=\sqrt[4]t y}=\sqrt[4] t\int_0^{\frac{1}{\sqrt[4]t}}\frac{1}{1+y^4}dy+\frac{1}{\sqrt[4] t}\int_0^{\frac{1}{\sqrt[4]t}}\frac{y^2}{1+y^4}dy$$
$$=\frac12\left(\sqrt[4] t+\frac{1}{\sqrt[4] t}\right)\int_0^{\frac{1}{\sqrt[4]t}}\frac{1+y^2}{1+y^4}dy+\frac12\left(\sqrt[4] t-\frac{1}{\sqrt[4] t}\right)\int_0^{\frac{1}{\sqrt[4]t}}\frac{1-y^2}{1+y^4}dy$$
$$=\frac12\left(\sqrt[4] t+\frac{1}{\sqrt[4] t}\right)\int_0^{\frac{1}{\sqrt[4]t}}\frac{\left(y-\frac1y \right)'}{\left(y-\frac1y \right)^2+2}dy-\frac12\left(\sqrt[4] t-\frac{1}{\sqrt[4] t}\right)\int_0^{\frac{1}{\sqrt[4]t}}\frac{\left(y+\frac1y \right)'}{\left(y+\frac1y \right)^2-2}dy$$
$$\small =\frac{1}{2\sqrt 2}\left(\sqrt[4] t+\frac{1}{\sqrt[4] t}\right)\left(\arctan\left(\frac{\sqrt[4]t-\frac{1}{\sqrt[4] t}}{\sqrt 2}\right)+\frac{\pi}{2}\right)+\frac1{4\sqrt 2}\left(\sqrt[4] t-\frac{1}{\sqrt[4] t}\right)\ln\left(\frac{\sqrt[4] t+\frac{1}{\sqrt[4] t}+\sqrt 2}{\sqrt[4] t+\frac{1}{\sqrt[4] t}-\sqrt 2}\right)$$

Comment: nice work. I knew you would come through for me (+1)

Answer (score 4):

Another approach might be exploiting 
$$\frac1{y^n+1}=\frac1n\sum^n_{k=1}\frac1{1-\omega_k y}$$ where $\omega_1,\cdots,\omega_n$ are the roots of $y^n+1=0$.

Hence,
$$T(n)= \frac1n\sum^n_{k=1}\int^{\pi/2}_0\frac1{1-\omega_k \sin x}dx$$

Integral calculator says that
$$\int^{\pi/2}_0\frac1{1-a\sin x}dx=\frac1{\sqrt{a^2-1}}\ln \frac{1+A^-}{1-A^+}$$ where
$$A^\pm=\sqrt{a^2-1}\pm a$$

Therefore,
$$T(n)= \frac1n\sum^n_{k=1}\Re  \frac1{\sqrt{\omega_k^2-1}}\ln \frac{1+\Omega_k^-}{1-\Omega_k^+} $$

This approach avoids complicated integration manipulations, at the price of doing tedious but basic complex analysis.

NB: I haven’t checked which branch of square root and logarithm should be taken.

Comment: Closest to a complete answer. Expect to be accepted once you work out all the details (+1)

Comment: @clathratus Thanks for the compliment. I will finish up the answer in the coming few days, and probably also find the closed form of $T(5)$ (which I expect to be composed of 10 terms).